# Set up a home network with different OSs

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, windows-xp, network-shares

Here's a picture of my current network:
[image]

I guess you will need a little bit of explanation here:

I have a router (LevelOne WBR-6005), which receive my WAN signal, provided by my ISP.

The only cable connection is to my Ubuntu server (unless there's a problem with the cable and I should use a USB WLAN adapter). My Ubuntu server is an old PC we had and decided to give it a new life.

My printer/scanner/copier a HP LaserJet 1120 MFP (WITHOUT network interface) is connected with USB 2.0 cable to the server and I need to know how to share it via SAMBA. Also I need to know how to show the server in the network, because it's not always visible (I can see the shared stuff when I type \\server in the address bar, but I don't always see it in the "Network" menu)

I also need to know how to set up a sharing environment for all the computers.

Don't think about the scanner, I already have a web application to scan (I installed xampp on the server).

If you have any questions feel free to ask and I'll try to explain.

So, guys any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

> Also I need to know how to show the server in the network, because it's not always visible

In a home network (no Active Directory) Windows is normally looking for other clients with NetBIOS. As an easy alternative you can resolve the names with WINS so you have to change the following line in the `[global]` section of `/etc/samba/smb.conf`:

```
[global]
os level = 99
wins support = yes
name resolve order = wins lmhosts hosts bcast
domain master = yes
preferred master = yes
```

1. Open the Properties dialog for the network interface you use to connect to the LAN. In XP, you can do this by hovering over the "Connect To..." option on the Start menu, right-clicking your interface, and clicking "Properties".
2. Select "Internet Protocol (TCP/IP)" from the list of protocols used on that interface and click "Properties".
3. Click "Advanced".
4. In the resulting "Advanced TCP/IP settings" dialog, select the WINS tab and click "Add...". Enter the IP address of your file server. You can probably leave the other settings at their defaults. Click OK on each of the configuration dialogs you have opened.
5. Open a DOS command window (Start -> Accessories -> Command Prompt) and enter the following three commands:

   - `ipconfig /release`
   - `ipconfig /renew`
   - `ipconfig /all`

The output from the last command should show that your Primary WINS Server has the IP address you entered above.

> My printer/scanner/copier a HP LaserJet 1120 MFP (WITHOUT network interface) is connected with USB 2.0 cable to the server and I need to know how to share it via SAMBA

I know two ways to share your Printer:

1. Make a printer share `print$`. Well explained example [here](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba_as_a_print_server#how_to_configure_printer_admin) (I'd prefer this method if you don't want to print from the server itself).
2. Install Cups on your Server and share the printer with IPP:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install cups cups-client cups-bsd hplip hpijs
   ```

   to install cups and:

   ```
   sudo cupsctl --share-printers  --remote-admin --remote-printers
   ```

   to share the printer and administrating cups over `http://localhost:631`.
3. On the Windows computer, go to the printer control panel and choose to "Add a New Printer". Next, choose to give a URL. For the URL, type in the location of the printer: `http://host_ip_address:631/printers/printer_name`

> set up a sharing environment for all the computers

Just add the following lines to `/etc/samba/smb.conf`:

```
[public]
path = /media/public
public = yes
writable = yes
```